# Using Xdebug with Eclipse and XAMPP (PHP 8)

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xampp, xdebug

I got the Xdebug running as I can see with `phpinfo()`.

From Eclipse (PDT) Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0) I can not start a Debuging-Session by using Port 9000 as preconfigured at several places i.e. in Debug-Configuration.

As I could read through the output of a `xdebug_info()` php-script Xdebug tried to use port 9003 at localhost. (Message there: "Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-("

If I change the port to 9003 the debugging works fine. But from there Eclipse stays in "Debug-Mode" meaning that also starting a php-script by "Run as PHP Web Application" starts a Debugging-Session as if I started a "Debug as PHP Web Application".

Changing again to Port 9000 gets me to the beginning. I'm quite confused about this...

Comment: The new version of XDEBUG V=3 uses port 9003 by default, the old version used 9000. They changed it as 9000 is used by something else. Eclipse has 2 ways of running a script. Only one will attempt to connect to XDEBUG. Check which you are using to launch your site/script

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But sorry for asking again... what do you mean with 2 ways running a script? I would like to either "run as ..." or "debug as..." without changing the port in preferences after I did either run or debug.

Comment: If I remember (took Eclipse off a few years ago) There is a `Run as` and a `Debug as` menu. So use the `Run as` when you dont want to debug

Comment: thats the problem. Once changed the debug-port to 9003 the "Run as" triggers a debug session as well.

Comment: Then you have changed more than you intended. I recently tried VSCode as an IDE, I quite like it. It is also getting a lot more maintenance that either Eclipse or Netbeans where PHP is concerned. I would suggest you have a look at that if you are not tied to Eclipse

Comment: Yes, I think I made a mistake somewhere in the preferences... Thanks for your hints!